# Compare and combine data in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to compare multiple lines in my list that contain a source IP, destination IP, packet time and size. I want to combine the data between all lines that have the same source IP and destination IP. For instance, if there are 2 or more lines with the same source and destination IP how do I combine all the data. I don't want to compare just the first and second row, I'm looking to match all lines in my list that have the same 172.217.2.161 (source) and 10.247.15.39 (destination), then extract the first timestamp and last timestamp into a new list.

```
def combine_data(source, dest, time, length):
    CombinePacket = [(source[i], dest[i], time[i], length[i]) for i in range(len(source))]
    NewData = []
    TotalSize = 0

    for i, j in zip(CombinePacket, CombinePacket[1:]):
        if(i[0:2] == j[0:2]):
            TotalSize = TotalSize + int(i[3])+int(j[3])
            data = i[0], i[1], i[2], j[2], TotalSize
            NewData.append(data)
```

List contains

```
[(['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31.044180', 46)]
[(['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31.044190', 29)]
[(['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31.044200' 50)]
```

Output should be

```
[['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'],'13:25:31.044180', '13:25:31.044200', 125]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my idea:

```
data = [
(['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31.044180', 46),
(['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31.044190', 29),
(['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31.044200', 50)
]
source = [d[0] for d in data]
dest = [d[1] for d in data]
time = [d[2] for d in data]
length = [d[3] for d in data]

from collections import defaultdict
import datetime
def combine_data(source, dest, time, length):
    CombinePacket = [(source[i], dest[i], time[i], length[i]) for i in range(len(source))]
    NewData = []
    TotalSize = 0

    data = defaultdict(list)
    for package in CombinePacket:
        data[(package[0][0],package[1][0])].append((package[2],package[3]))

    result = []
    for key,value in data.items():
        value = sorted(value,key = lambda x : x[0])
        first_time = value[0][0]
        last_time = value[-1][0]
        sum_length = sum(v[1] for v in value)
        result.append([key[0],key[1],first_time,last_time,sum_length])

    return result
```

Save your data into a dict with key equals `(source,dest)` and then sort the time to get the first and last timestamp and the totalsize is the sum of all size within that values

Answer (score 1):

You can do such sort of tasks using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from __future__ import print_function

import itertools


def key(packet):
    return packet[0], packet[1]  # source and destination


def do_combine_data(sources, destinations, times, lengths):
    packets = zip(sources, destinations, times, lengths)

    for (packet_source, packet_dest), group in itertools.groupby(
            sorted(packets, key=key), key=key):
        group = list(group)
        packet_sizes = [packet_size for (_, _, _, packet_size) in group]
        packet_times = [at for (_, _, at, _) in group]

        start_time, end_time = [func(packet_times) for func in (min, max)]
        total_size = sum(packet_sizes)

        yield packet_source, packet_dest, start_time, end_time, total_size
```

After that you can use it as you wish (even wrap `source` and `destination` in their own list):

```
def combine_data(source, dest, time, length):
    return [
        ([[s], [d], b, e, t])
        for s, d, b, e, t in do_combine_data(source, dest, time, length)]


def main():
    sources = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a"]
    destinations = ["b", "b", "b", "c", "c"]
    times = ["1", "2", "5", "3", "4"]
    lengths = [12, 11, 51, 89, 17]
    print(combine_data(sources, destinations, times, lengths))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output will be

```
[[['a'], ['b'], '1', '5', 74], [['a'], ['c'], '3', '4', 106]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my teacher is asking we use what was taught in class such as for loops, converting lists to dictionaries and so on. He doesn't want us importing anything other than regex.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a dictionary and update the values as you go, then convert them to a list. Assuming you have a list like:

```
data = [[(['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31.044180', 46)],
 [(['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31.044190', 29)],
 [(['172.217.2.161'], ['10.247.15.39'], '13:25:31.044200' 50)]]
```

Then:

```
d = dict()
for dat in data:
    sourceIp = dat[0][0][0]
    destIp = dat[0][1][0]
    minTs = dat[0][2]
    maxTs = dat[0][3]
    count = dat[0][4]
    k = (sourceIp, destIp)
    if (k not in d):
        d[k] = (minTs, maxTs, count)
    else:
        val = d[k]
        d[k] = (min(minTs, val[0]), max(maxTs, val[1]), count + val[2])


output = [ [[k[0]], [k[1]], v[0], v[1], v[2]] for (k,v) in d.items() ]
```

Of course,  you can build this dict up instead of the list in the first place to avoid the intermediary list. Also I'd recommend not having the singleton lists for the IPs if you don't need it, since it just leads to confusing indexing.

Comment: It says list index out of range when I try to do destIP =  data[0][1][0]. Is this the same as just doing destIP = data[1] to grab the second element in the list?

Comment: that might be it. Looking at your code, the way data is appended in your function is different from the way you represented the data in your second code block. You should be able to just get rid of the first [0] for all the fields

Comment: Since it's looping through my list which has element 0: source, 1: dest, 2: time: 3: length, how would minTs = dat[2] and maxTs = dat[3] grab first and last timestamp. It seems its just grabbing the timestamp for minTs and the length for maxTs